# finding contraction constant using mean value theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

We usually use mean value theorem to find the contraction constant if function is from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, can we extend this idea for any arbitrary metric space $X$ replacing $\mathbb{R}$? Can we generalize mean value theorem to any metric space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no. $\mathbb{R}$ has a lot of special properties going for it! Consider that even $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ doesn't have a mean value theorem, unless you allow the trick of only considering [values along a parametrized path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_in_several_variables): 
$$\mathbb{R} \overset{\gamma}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{R^n} \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{R},$$
in which case the composition $f \circ \gamma$ is really a map from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. And that's the *good* case---we can actually still do calculus with $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$! Even then, with $\mathbb{R}^2$ being about as nice of a metric space as you could hope for (metric space / normed space / Banach space / Hilbert space / Baire category / abelian Lie group / ...) the mean value theorem fails to generalize well.

We can, however, define the concept of a [Lipschitz continuous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) between *any* two metric spaces, which captures much of the same information.